# Bubble sort in Arraylist

Tags: java

I have tried a code to sort in descending order it workes fine for some input but for some it doesnt. eg. i tried 100,200,a,400 output is 400,200,a,100. but if i try d,1,4,c,9,6 output is d,6,9,c,4,1. I am supposed not to touch character. I have tried.

```
String input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter a string:");
String[] abc = input.split(",");
ArrayList<String> num = new ArrayList<String>();
for (int i = 0; i < abc.length; i++) {
    num.add(abc[i]);
}

for ( int z = 0; z < num.size() -1 ; z ++ ) {
    int numI;
    try {
        numI = Integer.parseInt(num.get(z));
    }
    catch (NumberFormatException nfe) {
        continue;
    }

    for (int j = z + 1; j < num.size(); j ++ ) {
        int numJ;
        try {
            numJ = Integer.parseInt(num.get(j));
        } 
        catch (NumberFormatException nfe)
        {
            continue;
        }
        if (numI < numJ)
        {
            String temp = num.get(z);   //swapping
            num.set(z, num.get(j));
            num.set(j, temp);
        }
    }
}
for(String el:num){
    System.out.print(el+",");
}
```

What is wrong here?

Comment: wouldn't it be much easier, to first parse the complete input into integers, and afterwards sort?

Comment: In decimal, characters like `d` and `c` will throw a number format exception when trying to parse, so you skip them. Instead just use `String#compareTo(String)`. No need to parse as an int.

Comment: You're implementing bubble sort incorrectly.  It looks like you're comparing elements (0,1) then (0,2) then (0,3) etc when the actual order is (0,1) (1,2) (2,3) .... then (1,2) (2,3) ....

Comment: @Obicere it appears the problem is to sort the numbers and leave the non-numbers in-place, using bubble sort, sorting in decreasing order

Comment: @epylar What should i do?

Comment: The introduction of the fixed place strings is a little tricky.  I would suggest first getting bubble sort working on a list of just integers, in a function, and run some test cases against it.  Then when you're confident that works, you can move to the next step of solving your complete problem.

Comment: By the way, unit tests don't hurt, and it's a good skill to learn.  In this case it would even be easy to do TDD.  Check that your function works with an empty array or list, with null, with an empty array or list with a single value, etc. Add one check to your test suite at a time, make sure it fails, then modify your function to make it pass.  It'll be a bit of a pain the first time you do it, but like I said it's a good skill to learn.

Comment: @epylar i tried testing integer only it works fine, but can't figure out what is wrong when i enter string. Can you help?

Comment: @koshishkharel What code changes have you tried?

Comment: @epylar i don't know what to do above code is supposed to be correct.

Comment: @koshishkharel Say you have a list with five elements (ignore the fact that you're not considering non-numbers for the moment).  You're comparing element 1 to element 2, then element 1 to element 3, then 1-4, 1-5; then 2-3 2-4 2-5; 3-4 3-5; 4-5.  You should be comparing: 1-2 2-3 3-4 4-5; 2-3 3-4 4-5; 3-4 4-5; 4-5.