# How can a collection.sort display output in reverse order?

Tags: java

Can collection.sort display output in descending order leaving the character in same place? eg. Input=100,200,a,300 Output=300,200,a,100.
I am using Arraylist which is String type.

```
String input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter a string:"); 
String[] abc = input.split(",");
ArrayList<String> num = new ArrayList<String>();
for (int i = 0; i < abc.length; i++)
{
    num.add(abc[i]);
}
Collections.sort(num, Collections.reverseOrder());
System.out.println(num);
```

Comment: No. You will need to create your own Comparator.

Comment: That looks like a XY problem; one thing is sure, you can't use `Collections.sort()` for that.

Comment: Here i have tried using bubble shot, but i dont khow what is wrong.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29148652/bubble-sort-in-arraylist

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One can use Collections.reverseOrder() comparator to sort the list in reverse order.

```
public class CollectionsDemo {
public static void main(String args[]) {  
  // create linked list object         
  LinkedList list = new LinkedList();  

  // populate the list 
  list.add(-28);  
  list.add(20);  
  list.add(-12);  
  list.add(8);  

  // create comparator for reverse order
  Comparator cmp = Collections.reverseOrder();  

  // sort the list
  Collections.sort(list, cmp);  

  System.out.println("List sorted in ReverseOrder: ");      
  for(int i : list){
     System.out.println(i+ " ");
  } 
  }
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

You may try to create your own comparator like this:

```
static <K,V extends Comparable<? super V>> 
            List<Entry<K, V>> reverseSortValues(Map<K,V> map) 
{

    List<Entry<K,V>> lst = new ArrayList<Entry<K,V>>(map.entrySet());

    Collections.sort(lst, 
            new Comparator<Entry<K,V>>() 
            {
                @Override
                public int compare(Entry<K,V> e1, Entry<K,V> e2) 
                {
                    return e2.getValue().compareTo(e1.getValue());
                }
            }
    );

    return lst;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Create comparator for reverse order -

```
Comparator cmp = Collections.reverseOrder();
```

Then sort the list -

```
Collections.sort(num, cmp);
```

The `Collections.reverseOrder()` is used to get a `Comparator` that reverses the  natural ordering.